# The size of tablespace file ./sys/sys_config.ibd is only 81920, should be at least 98304

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, mysql-8.0

When I try to run Mysql:8.0.2 on docker compose file, I am getting this error.

```
2020-05-31T10:01:26.220397Z 4 [System] [MY-013381] [Server] Server upgrade from '80019' to '80020' started.
mysql-server_1             | mbind: Operation not permitted
mysql-server_1             | 2020-05-31T10:01:32.357417Z 4 [ERROR] [MY-012094] [InnoDB] The size of tablespace file ./sys/sys_config.ibd is only 81920, should be at least 98304!
mysql-server_1             | 2020-05-31T10:01:32.357944Z 4 [ERROR] [MY-013183] [InnoDB] Assertion failure: fil0fil.cc:2400 thread 140593248143104
```

could you please tell me what was the problem here. Here is my my.cnf details

```
 [mysqld]
 pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
 socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
 datadir         = /var/lib/mysql
 #secure-file-priv= NULL
 secure-file-priv= ""
 # Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
 symbolic-links=0
 innodb_force_recovery = 0
 # Custom config should go here
 !includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
 #bind-address = *
 skip-grant-tables
 innodb_file_per_table=1
 innodb_data_file_path=ibdata1:10M:autoextend
```